# (Apache) Forbidden 403 when accessing subdomain

Tags: apache, http, xampp, subdomain, httpd.conf

I want to set up the subdomain "shop" on my Apache 2.2 server on Windows/XAMPP and it redirects to "index.html" if I enter "shop.localhost" as the URL but once I try to connect via my domain "sv443.net" it redirects to my document root ("/index.html" instead of "/shop/index.html"). Connecting to "sv443.net/shop/" works fine though and even redirects to "index.html".

**I'm using Cloudflare to handle the DNS stuff and added these records (I cut off the IP address part):**

[image]

**This is my httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAdmin sven.fehler@web.de

   DocumentRoot "c:/users/sv443/desktop/mamp htdocs"

   <Directory "c:/users/sv443/desktop/mamp htdocs">
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None

     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted

   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost shop.localhost:80>
   ServerName shop.localhost
   ServerAdmin sven.fehler@web.de

   DocumentRoot "c:/users/sv443/desktop/mamp htdocs/shop"

   <Directory "c:/users/sv443/desktop/mamp htdocs/shop">
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None

     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all

     Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**And this is my hosts.dat:**

```
(only comments)

2.205.169.73 sv443.net

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


127.0.0.1   localhost   shop.localhost
```

**Also I added this .htaccess file to the shop directory to redirect to the index.html if a 403 or 404 is encountered - removing this file doesn't fix my problem:**

```
ErrorDocument 403 /shop/index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/index.html
```

**If someone tries to connect I get this error message in the Apache error.log:**

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/Sv443/Desktop/MAMP htdocs/shop/.html
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: After waiting an hour it almost works. If I connect to "https://shop.sv443.net/" I get redirected to the document root ("/index.html" instead of "/shop/index.html")

Answer (score 0):

If you can get content by explicitly specifying "/index.html" but not with "/", you should add `DirectoryIndex index.html` in your configuration, after loading mod_dir. This will define the default file to look for when it is not specified.

For your VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog "logs/example_access_log" combined
    ErrorLog  "logs/example_error_log"

    [... REST OF CONFIGURATION ...]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.localhost
    ServerAlias shop.example.com

    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog "logs/shop_access_log" combined
    ErrorLog  "logs/shop_error_log"

    [... REST OF CONFIGURATION ...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache decides which VirtualHost to use for the request based on the domain in the request.  If it does not find a match, it uses the first one in the file (here localhost).  Therefore you are not pointing to your "shop" sub-domain, unless you specify it in the VirtualHost for it, via `ServerAlias ...`.

Comment: That only fixed the issue I had with the "shop.localhost". I can now connect to it via localhost exactly how I wanted to. But still, using my public domain "shop.sv443.net" redirects to the document root instead. I have updated the question.

Comment: Also, does it have to be .com? Because I have a .net domain.

Comment: No, it is just that in answers here we always use www.example.com, since that domain does exist and is setup for this.  You can use any domain name you want.  Replace all example.com by "sv443.net" and it should be ok.

Comment: Sadly that still doesn't work. I have tried all combinations, even in the hosts.dat file.

Comment: Did you make sure sv443.net does send the request to your Apache?  Add one access log per VirtualHost (I edited my answer to show how) and confirm you are getting all requests in the first VH please.